# Why can't DSolve solve this simple system of PDEs?

Tags: differential-equations

I have a system of two PDEs:
$$\frac{\partial\psi}{\partial y}=ax+b$$
$$-\frac{\partial\psi}{\partial x}=-ay+cx$$
where $a$, $b$, and $c$ are constant reals. When I plug the system into `DSolve`:

```
DSolve[{D[ψ[x, y], y] == a x + b, -D[ψ[x, y], x] == -a y + c x}, ψ[x, y], {x, y}]
```

I don't get any answer. Why?

Comment: Your second equation has an extra `-` in the Mathematica code.  In any case, do you know of a solution yourself?

Comment: `DSolve[{D[\[Psi][x, y], y] == a x + b, D[\[Psi][x, y], x] == a y - c x}, \[Psi][x, y], {x, y}]` works. For some reason it doesn't seem to like it when you multiply both sides of the 2nd equations by -1. On the whole, though, you have to keep in mind that these sort of equations possibly have no solution.

Comment: @ChrisK Oh, I actually forgot to put the minus sign in the equation above

Comment: @SjoerdSmit thank you! that worked for me

Comment: It does seem surprising that a trivial transformation of this equation changes it from one that Mathematica can't handle into one that it can.

Comment: Although `DSolve` often cannot solve simple sets of PDEs, this case is so egregious that it may be a bug.  I suggest you report it to Wolfram, Inc.

Comment: @SjoerdSmit How about posting this as an answer?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First of all, it's important to keep in mind that systems like these do not necessarily have a solution. A simple example would be the following:

```
DSolve[
 {
  D[\[Psi][x, y], x] == y,
  D[\[Psi][x, y], y] == 2 x
  },
 \[Psi][x, y],
 {x, y}
]
```

> > *Returns unevaluated*

This is how `DSolve` tells you it couldn't find a solution. If you differentiate the first equation w.r.t `y` and the 2nd w.r.t. `x` you get `D[\[Psi][x, y], x, y] == 1` and `D[\[Psi][x, y], y, x] == 2`. Since the order of differentiation shouldn't matter, `D[\[Psi][x, y], x, y] == D[\[Psi][x, y], y, x]` should hold, but clearly that's not the case here.

With that out of the way, `DSolve` works for the following equations:

```
DSolve[
 {
  D[\[Psi][x, y], y] == a x + b,
  D[\[Psi][x, y], x] == a y - c x
  },
 \[Psi][x, y],
 {x, y}
]

Out[2] = {{\[Psi][x, y] -> -((c x^2)/2) + b y + a x y + C[1]}}
```

Unfortunately, `DSolve` seems rather fussy and doesn't like it when you multiply an equation with a constant factor:

```
DSolve[
 {
  D[\[Psi][x, y], y] == a x + b,
  2 D[\[Psi][x, y], x] == 2 (a y - c x)
  },
 \[Psi][x, y],
 {x, y}
]
```

> > *Returns unevaluated*

*edit*
I just reported this bug